# Display "Busy Indicator" using background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am doing some heavy computations on the main thread and these computations cannot run on a separate thread.

I want to display a "Busy Indicator" (i.e., spinning widget) on the application UI when these computations are running. As such, I cannot show the busy indicator on main thread as the UI is locked while these computations are running.

To work around this issue, I tried to move the busy indicator to separate thread. With the help of [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx) I am able to place the busy indicator on separate thread. However, I am not able to communicate with this thread to start or stop the busy indicator.

```
     private HostVisual CreateBusyIndicatorOnWorkerThread()

    {
        // Create the HostVisual that will "contain" the VisualTarget
        // on the worker thread.
        HostVisual hostVisual = new HostVisual();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(BusyIndicatorWorkerThread));
        thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start(hostVisual);
        // Wait for the worker thread to spin up and create the VisualTarget.
        s_event.WaitOne();
        return hostVisual;
    }

 private static AutoResetEvent s_event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
 private void BusyIndicatorWorkerThread(object arg)

    {
        // Create the VisualTargetPresentationSource and then signal the
        // calling thread, so that it can continue without waiting for us.
        HostVisual hostVisual = (HostVisual)arg;
        VisualTargetPresentationSource visualTargetPS = new VisualTargetPresentationSource(hostVisual);
        s_event.Set();

        // Create a MediaElement and use it as the root visual for the
        // VisualTarget.
        visualTargetPS.RootVisual = CreateBusyIndicator();

        // Run a dispatcher for this worker thread.  This is the central
        // processing loop for WPF.
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }

  private FrameworkElement CreateBusyIndicator()

    {
        var busyIndicator = new MyBusyIndicator();
        //busyIndicator.DataContext = this.
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("IsBusy");
        myBinding.Source = this;
        busyIndicator.SetBinding(MyBusyIndicator.IsBusyProperty, myBinding);
     }
```

I always gets an exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". This is because I am trying to update the busy indicator from the main thread while the busy indicator is owned by a different thread.

I have also tried an approach given in [this article](http://abrahamheidebrecht.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/creating-a-busy-indicator-in-a-separate-thread-in-wpf/),

```
private void CreateAndShowContent()
    {
        Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        VisualTargetPresentationSource source =
            new VisualTargetPresentationSource(_hostVisual);
        _sync.Set();
        source.RootVisual = _createContent();
        DesiredSize = source.DesiredSize;
        _invalidateMeasure();

        Dispatcher.Run();
        source.Dispose();
    }
```

But with this approach Dispatcher.Run() nothing happens until after the completion of the computations and then the busy indicator is displayed.

I want to communicate from main thread to the thread having busy indicator. Does anyone have an approach?

Comment: Please provide a reason why these operations cannot run on any other thread then the UI thread? I don't see any practical reasons there.

Comment: Rather than doing non-UI work in the UI thread and doing UI work in a non-UI thread, reverse it.  Do your UI work in the UI thread and your non-UI work in a non-UI thread.  That's simply the design of the entire system you're using.

Comment: I am using a third party library that does that computation & checks for the caller thread to be main thread. So we can't change their implementation so we have to do our UI on different thread.

Comment: @Ahmed My guess is that either you're using the third party library improperly, in some way, shape or form, or it's not written to be used in a UI context such as this, and as such is not an acceptable solution to your problem and you'll need to not use it.  Consider contacting some support services of that 3rd party to investigate how you can use their product properly.

Comment: What is the “third party library”?

Comment: @Ahmed - how could it know that the caller thread is the main thread?

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to run *"heavy computations"* in UI thread. Even more - this is a bad practice. Instead use `BackgroundWorker` which will do work, meantime alive UI-thread will show *Loading/Calculating*:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (s, e) => {
   // This part will last at a separate thread without blocking UI.
   // Excellent place for heavy computations.
}

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {
   // Here we're back to UI thread - so you can change states and stop animations.
}

// And finally start async computation
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

UI should contain `BusyIndicator` control which will be *activated/stopped* when you'll *start/finish* worker.

Comment: I am using a third party library that does that computation & checks for the caller thread to be the main thread. So we can't change their implementation so we have to do our UI on different thread

Comment: @Ahmed Can you add some references/links or describe what kind of library is it?

Comment: hey @AnatoliiGabuza, this code saves my week. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please stop what you are doing... it is totally incorrect. @Anatolii Gabuza was correct... you *shouldn't* do *any* long running process using the UI thread as this will block it, making the application unusable at these times. Unless your long running process is rendering UI objects, then there really is *no* reason to do it using the UI thread... let us know what it is and we can help you to run it on a background thread correctly.

So you discovered that you can't display your busy indicator on the UI thread because it is busy with your long running process... at this point, most developers would realise their error, but unfortunately, not you. Instead of accepting that the long running process should be run on a background thread, you do the exact opposite and now want to display some UI element in a background thread, while blocking the UI thread with a long running process???

This is utter madness, if you want to avoid some horrendous problems, please stop. If you continue, then you'd better get used to seeing that exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke it busyContainer dispatcher. use as below

```
this.busyContainer.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        //update busy Container
                    }));
```

Answer (score -4):

I got this from SO but cannot find it on SO
Run this on the UI thread and put in your task where very long task is

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private Cursor _previousCursor;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        _previousCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = _previousCursor;
    }

    #endregion
}

using (new WaitCursor())
{
    // very long task
}
```

Comment: This won't do anything because the UI thread is being blocked.

Comment: @Servy Did you test it?  I use this a lot.

Comment: You frequently perform long running non-UI operations in the UI thread of your application?  And you don't see why that's a bad idea?

Comment: @Servy Visual Studio displays an hour glass for some operations.  You don't see had that is a good idea?